# Looking for words that start with a character in an array

Tags: c

In a char array, I am trying to pick out words that begin with a character or has that character in the word. What can I use to accomplish this? Thank You!

if I have an array that states, "Farming fun alf is good."
My output should be:
  Farming 
  fun
  alf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

char list[50];
int i;




  fgets(list, 50, stdin);     //retrieve the string from the user
  for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  if(list[i] == 'z'){
     printf("%c", list[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I have tried fgets to retrieve the input from the user. I am now trying to use a for loop to loop through the array and find words that start with the letter.

Comment: what is the algorithm behind this? How do you get the output farming fun alf?

Comment: So, the output will be words in the char array that have the letter "f". Those words are farming, fun, and alf.

Comment: So, what interface have you designed for your function(s)?  What is `main()` going to do and what does it delegate to functions?   Is the `main()` function going to print the words or one of the others?  How are you going to handle multiple words?

Comment: This is all composed in main(). The other words in the array are to be skipped over

Comment: Why can't you use `strchr()`?  Also, your example is not clear.  In your example, what is the letter you are searching for?  If it is `i` why didn't it grab `Farming` and if it is `f` then why not `fun`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it still appears you want to find words containing `'F'` or `'f'` given your input and output -- your posted code looking for `if(list[i] == 'z')` is quite bewildering...  No matter what you want to accomplish, you will never parse words containing `'F'` or `'f'` from the line of input checking for `'z'`.

Everybody needs a bit of help, so let's start with what it looks like you need to accomplish given `"Farming fun alf is good."` and you want `"Farming fun alf"` out. The basic steps you will need to accomplish are:

1. read input from user into valid storage;
2. split the input into individual words (called *tokenizing* the string); and
3. check if any character in each word is `'F'` or `'f'`, output the word if found.

**Read Input From User**

You are to be commended for choosing `fgets` to take input from your user. That (along with POSIX `getline`) would be a good choice. Regardless of what input function you choose, you need to ***validate*** the input by ***checking the return*** (at minimum) to ensure the user provided valid input and didn't cancel by generating a manual `EOF` (<kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows), and in your case you should also validate that the user entered characters and didn't simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can do that similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC  1024  /* if you need a constanst, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char str[MAXC];                     /* storage for string */
    ...
    fputs ("enter string: ", stdout);   /* prompt */
    /* validate user provided input, not ctrl+d(z) or just [Enter] */
    if (!fgets (str, MAXC, stdin) || *str == '\n') {
        fputs ("(user canceled or empty input)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

Now you have your user input (up to `1023` characters) stored in `str` with the `'\n'` character appended to the end.

**Tokenize `str` Into Words**

While there are many ways to tokenize a string into words, a simple approach is to use the aptly named `strtok` function. See [strtok(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) for details of its use. In summary, it takes the string to be tokenized as its input on the first call and a string of delimiters to split the string into words with. (on all subsequent calls, `NULL` is passed in place of the original `str`).

**Note:** `strtok` modifies the original `str` so you cannot pass a *string-literal* or other immutable string. (make a copy of `str` if you need to preserve the original)

To tokenize with `strtok` you could do:

```
    const char *delim = " \t\n.?!",     /* delimiters to split str */
               *find = "fF";            /* chars to test for */
    ...
    /* tokenize str into words */
    for (char *p = strtok(str, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim)) {
        /* test for characters here */
    }
```

The `for` loop above declares a character pointer `p` as the loop variable (initialized to the return from `strtok(str, delim)` which will be a pointer to the first word. The loop then checks `p` (e.g. `p != NULL`) as the loop conditional, and increments with `p = strtok (NULL, delim)` on each iteration to ensure `p` points to the next word. You may think of the logic a little easier as:

```
    char *p = strtok(str, delim);
    while (p != NULL) {
        /* test for characters here */
        p = strtok (NULL, delim);
    }
```

(both are equivalent)

**Check If Word Contains Characters to Find**

To check if a word contains one of any number of characters, the `strpbrk` function is tailor made. See [strtok(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html). `strtok` will locate the first occurrence of any one of the characters you provide in a delimiter string (named `find` declared above), e.g.

```
        if (strpbrk (p, find)) {    /* does word contain fF? */
            ...
```

That's it. Now you simply need to fill in the logic to output the words found above. You can simply `printf (" %s", p);`. Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC  1024  /* if you need a constanst, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char str[MAXC];                     /* storage for string */
    const char *delim = " \t\n.?!",     /* delimiters to split str */
               *find = "fF";            /* chars to test for */

    fputs ("enter string: ", stdout);   /* prompt */
    /* validate user provided input, not ctrl+d(z) or just [Enter] */
    if (!fgets (str, MAXC, stdin) || *str == '\n') {
        fputs ("(user canceled or empty input)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    /* tokenize str into words */
    for (char *p = strtok(str, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim)) {
        if (strpbrk (p, find)) {    /* does word contain fF? */
            printf (" %s", p);      /* output with space */
        }
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtokspn
enter string: Farming fun alf is good.
 Farming fun alf
```

This is not the only way to do it, but probably one of the more succinct ways to approach the problem. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank You for your help. Maybe one day I'll be as good as you are.

Comment: David, Thanks for the help so far. I have another question if you don't mind. So, instead of a hardcoded character to find, how could i make the last element in the string that character to find?

Comment: OK, you mean like `'d'` in `"Farming fun alf is good."` or would that be `'.'`? The last character in the string is always at index `strlen(str) - 1`. If you want to find the last `'d'` instead of `'.'`, you can do `char *p = str + strlen(str) - 1;` and `while (p > str && !isascii(p)) p--;` (`p` initialized to point to the last char, and while it isn't the beginning and it's not ASCII -- backup to next previous char) When the loop stops, `p` will point to the last ASCII character in `str` (or if `p == str`, no ASCII characters were found).

Comment: Or you can do the same with indexes. `size_t last = strlen(str) - 1;` and then `while (last > 0 && !isascii(str[last])) last--;` Or you can do the same in a `for` loop, e.g. `size_t last; for (last = strlen(str) - 1; last > 0 && !isascii(str[last]); last--) {}` or you could do `size_t last; for (last = strlen(str) - 1; last > 0; last--) if (isascii(str[last])) break;` (`last` declared before loop to survive after loop exits to make index available)